# How to remove 2 hours from all rows of a column string represent date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a text Column in mysql which the data of it represent date and time
the format is like this: 2018-03-06 03:18:17pm

Sometimes this colum instead of date show the word "NO"

I need to remove 2 hours from all of the rows
in the table.

would be happy for a code example.

the table name is: r_238
the col name is:Answer

Thanks for all who answer.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody is going to do your homework unless you show some effort first. This effort starts with a clear example and a description of what you tried so far.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt . . . It would be quite sad if this were homework.  Students should not be learning that date/time values are ever stored in databases as strings.

Comment: I am not a student and not a mysql programer however search on the web and didnot found an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck.  MySQL will recognize that format as a valid `datetime`, so you can just convert the column to a `datetime`.  The rest is easy:

```
update r_238
    set answer = nullif(answer, 'NO');

alter table r_238 modify column answer datetime;

update r_238
    set answer = answer - interval 2 hour;
```

In the future, use proper types for your columns. `datetime` values should be stored as `datetime`, not as a string.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'columnAnswer' in 'r_238'

Comment: @ברקרוזנפלד . . . There is no identifier called `columnAnswer` in this answer.  You can remove the keyword `column` from the `alter table`, it is optional.

Comment: I edited my questions
since I got this error Incorrect datetime value: 'NO' for column 'answer' at row 1

Comment: @ברקרוזנפלד . . . Then your original statement is wrong, and the column is not in the format you specify.  I would suggest that you investigate your table more, because answering the question you asked will not help you.

Comment: if there is no date in coulm it will show the word :"NO" not any more complex things

Comment: @ברקרוזנפלד . . . `NULL` should be used for that purpose.

Comment: Yes I undetrstood that Null should be use however this is not the case...

Comment: got this  error: #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-06 03:44:52pm' for column 'answer' at row 517

Comment: @ברקרוזנפלד . . . That should be fine.  Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/20259.  Perhaps the string value has some hidden or unrecognized characters.  In any case, are you starting to understand why you want use the correct types in a database?  Having to manage values that are strings is really a pain.